# invalid json response body at http://localhost:3000/api/user/[object%20Object] reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: json, reactjs, express, authentication, next.js

I'm using this example to create a simple authentication with Nextjs https://github.com/vvo/next-iron-session/tree/master/examples/next.js

but instead of fetching the user JSON object from Github (as the example does) im trying to do it from my mongodb database where i have some users.

I did this on my `login.js` file:

```
import fetchJson from "../../lib/fetchJson";
import withSession from "../../lib/session";
import { withIronSession } from "next-iron-session";
import { connectToDatabase } from "../../util/mongodb";

export default withSession(async (req, res) => {
  const { db } = await connectToDatabase();

  const { username } = await req.body;
  
  const foundUser = await db.collection("users").findOne({"userName": username});

  console.log(foundUser) // <--- this returns the user object on console just fine
  
  
  const url = `http://localhost:3000/api/user/${foundUser}`;

  try {

    const { userName, email } = await fetchJson(url);
    const user = { isLoggedIn: true, userName, email }
    
    
    req.session.set("user", user);
    await req.session.save();
    res.json(user);
  } catch (error) {
    const { response: fetchResponse } = error;
    res.status(fetchResponse?.status || 500).json(error.data);
    
  }
});
```

And i have this code on my `/api/user.js` file:

```
import withSession from "../../lib/session";
import { connectToDatabase } from "../../util/mongodb";

export default withSession(async (req, res) => {
  const user = req.session.get("user");

  
  if (user) {
    
    const { db } = await connectToDatabase();
    
    const foundUser = await db.collection("users").findOne({"userName": user.userName, "email": user.email});

    console.log("useri pi te user.js " + foundUser)
    
    // in a real world application you might read the user id from the session and then do a database request
    // to get more information on the user if needed

res.json({
      
      isLoggedIn: true,
      ...user,
    });
  } else {
    res.json({
      isLoggedIn: false,
    });
  }
});
```

But i get "invalid json response body at http://localhost:3000/api/user/[object%20Object] reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" error even though i get the user object printed in the console just fine.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: check out the url in your error: `http://localhost:3000/api/user/[object%20Object] ` does that look right to you?

Comment: i see that its not right and also tried JSON.stringify but didnt fix it

Comment: what do you want that url to look like?`

Comment: `const url = `http://localhost:3000/api/user/${foundUser}`;`

Comment: that also is not a valid url... can you give a real example of a url that works? Without variables in it?

Comment: i want it to be dynamic depending on the user who is currently logged in

Comment: I understand that, but it would be helpful to see a _specific_ example to figure out how to fix your code to do that.

Comment: when i hardcode it as `const url = `http://localhost:3000/api/user/lisi`;` or when i get the user from the input field `const url = `http://localhost:3000/api/user/${username}`;` i get almost the same error just instead of `[object%20Object]` i get the username: `invalid json response body at http://localhost:3000/api/user/lisi reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

Comment: Ok that's progress. Now we know that you want the _username_ in there, and it sounds like you figured out how to do that. The issue now is that the URL `http://localhost:3000/api/user/lisi` probably doesn't return JSON. What does it actually return?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Ok, so your url is also wrong: `http://localhost:3000/api/user/lisi`. There's no JSON here... if you expect that URL to work, you need to fix this first. There's no code in your question related to that endpoint. If you intended to build it, fix that before you start working on clients.

Comment: I think `user.js` file is responsible for that but its not fetching that JSON and i dont know why.

Comment: Nobody here would be able to answer that question for you. The code responsible for serving that API endpoint is not in this question. Your `user.js` doesn't seem responsible for this because it works on the session/current user and not on anything in the url.

Comment: Once you manage to make sure that `http://localhost:3000/api/user/lisi` returns something, your original problem should be fixed.

Comment: but how do i get that JSON from database? it gets printed in the console though. If you see the original example im using, it gets the JSON from the github api. im serving the same from my mongodb database and it throws that error. i cant find what im missing

Comment: if i use this url `const url = `http://localhost:3000/api/user/ ` above in the `login.js` file, it loggs in but the user is `null`

Comment: Considering deleting this question, and creating a new, more focused question. It sounds like you're having a lot of debugging issues, that arent' all related... and asking questions until you have working code doesn't work that well with stack overflow.